# Magento 2.4.2: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: magento2, php, frontend, composer, dependency

Running the command `composer update --with-all-dependencies`  when trying to upgrade Magento 2.4.2  to 2.4.4. throws this message in red `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` Below is the full error message that I see in the terminal.

[image]

Please note I updated PHP to 8.1 and composer to 2.3.10 before I started the upgrade process. I would request any suggestions/fixes for this issue.

Below are the set of commands I'm planning to run to upgrade. Please confirm if these ones are correct.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update

composer update --ignore-platform-reqs

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento s:d:c

php bin/magento in:rein

php bin/magento c:c
```

Comment: Exectue below commands.

composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.4 --no-update

Comment: composer update

Comment: What you get after above command?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/composer.json

Comment: When I executed the first command in your comment above, I got about 5 prompts like this `
magento/magento-composer-installer contains a Composer plugin which is currently not in your allow-plugins config. See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins
Do you trust "magento/magento-composer-installer" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?] `

Comment: I typed `Y` for all five prompts.

Comment: yes, with check with Y

Comment: Same error even after answering Y to all. The error is same as the one in the image above in this post.

Comment: Rename Composer.json file and download composer.json file from 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/composer.json

and execute composer update command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137867/discussion-between-codeforgood-and-s-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clone the repo somewhere (can be outside your project folder, since the tool is taking care of symlinking the individual modules):

```
 git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data.git ~/sample-data
```

Then run the "installer" script:

```
php -f ~/sample-data/dev/tools/build-sample-data.php -- --ce-source="$PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO2_PROJECTROOT"
```

After that run the update script:

```
cd $PATH_TO_YOUR_MAGENTO2_PROJECTROOT
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And you should see the sample data being installed (takes a while...):

```
[...]
Module 'Magento_DownloadableSampleData':
Installing data..
Module 'Magento_ThemeSampleData':
Installing data..
Module 'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData':
Installing data..
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':
Installing data..
Module 'Magento_BundleSampleData':
Installing data..
Module 'Magento_ProductLinksSampleData':
Installing data..
Module 'Magento_ReviewSampleData':
Installing data..
[...]
Don't forget to clear caches and fix permissions and you should see all the sample data in the backend and the frontend now...
```